# Importing SQL Server Bit Type into MS Access Database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I import bit type data from the ODBC linked SQL Servers into my MS Access database, the value is displayed incorrectly.

For example, in the SQL Server, the value is `1`, but when it comes over, it becomes `-1`. I've been trying different number configurations in the Access database, but the value is still coming over as `-1`.

It's only the bit type data. How can I correct this?

Comment: I don't think you need to correct this unless you want it to be an integer rather than a boolean/bit. That's just the way booleans work in Access.

Comment: You can just update the values after the import with `update mytable set mycolumn = 1 where mycolumn = -1`

Comment: @Bohemian I may be mistaken, but if the data has been imported as a boolean field in MS Access (as opposed to an ODBC linked table to SQL Server), the field can only hold the values `-1` & `0` and so, whilst your suggested query won't error, the new value of `1` will be interpreted & stored as `-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boolean values in MS Access are represented by signed integers whose binary representation is either all ones (`True`) or all zeros (`False`).

For example, for a 32-bit implementation:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = True  = -1
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 = False =  0
```

Since signed integers are stored in binary using [Two's-Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, a binary value of all ones will mean that the [sign bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_bit) is also set, thereby yielding the integer `-1`.

---

Conversely, SQL Server is far more memory efficient, only using a single bit (instead of the 32 or 64 used by MS Access) to store a boolean value, with `0` representing False and `1` representing True.

Comment: Add check for true should be`val  <> 0`to cover different representations.forrepresentationTruerepresentation.

Comment: The odbc driver takes care of this. In Access sql, you can use True/False, -1,0, or even on/off. All queries in Access should work fine - including imported data, or even live linked tables. On the sql server side - there is no true/false. You have to use 1 for true,and 0 for false. But any sql on the access client side will not have to be changed and will run correct as before. that means you CONTINUE to use True/false. Even against that table that correctly shows -1, or 0 you find true/false also works. You can change the display of -1,0 to true/false in the linked table or local table.